# About 'to have been'

Tags: verbs

> 1)‎I am to have been here for two hours by now.
>   (Here, what I want to describe is that by now, it's been already for two hours that I have been here.)
>
> 2)I am to have been here for two hours until he comes home.
>   (Here, what I want to describe is that it will be taken for about two hours to wait for him coming home.)
>
> 3)I am to have met her, as soon as I went out of my home.
>   (Here, I want to describe a simultaneous situation where I get to meet her in front of my home, as soon as I leave my home.)

The sentences are written by me to know how to interpret 'to have been' in such a context, and whether they are grammatical.

Comment: Your sentences do not make good sense. The temporal phrases  are not being used properly in combination.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yes, I deliberately wrote them even though I know it is not popular to write like that just to see how the sentences are to be read by native speakers.

Comment: They read as borderline gibberish.

Comment: am to be = "required to be",  or "shall be" (passive) when in combination with past-participle of transitive verb.   *You are to be here at 8PM sharp!* and *I am to be given an award next week for biggest pumpkin.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to know how to express those ideas, and are not running a bunch of marginal sentences past native-speaker guinea-pigs...

*(Here, what I want to describe is that by now, it's been already for two hours that I have been here.)*

> I have been here for two hours already.

*(Here, what I want to describe is that it will be taken for about two hours to wait for him coming home.)*

> I will have been waiting for two hours by the time he comes home.
>
> By the time he comes home, I will have been waiting for two hours.

*(Here, I want to describe a simultaneous situation where I get to meet her in front of my home, as soon as I leave my home.)*

> I will (get to) meet her as soon as I leave the house.